# List CakePHP File Upload error codes

Tags: file, cakephp, upload

Anyway, can anyone give me the error code definitions for when files are uploaded in cakePHP.

So my $this-data contains something like this,

Array
(
    [file] => Array
    (
        [name] => cake.jpg
        [type] => image/jpeg
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/hp1083.tmp
        [error] => 1
        [size] => 24530
    )
)

What does [error] = 1 indicate?

While you're at it can you list the break down of all the numbers, then maybe it'll be easier for others to find it the future

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a file upload component?  If not, file upload error codes should be the same as the standard PHP error codes.  I find it hard to believe that you can't google this answer.

Comment: When you're looking for cakephp file upload error codes, it is hard to google.  I didn't realize it was the same array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

File upload has nothing to do with CakePHP.

$this->data contains what $_FILE contains, it is a HTTP/PHP specific array.

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php), [$_FILE](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php), and the [error codes](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).